# Google Analytics filters not working properly with Tag Manager and multiple subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, google-tag-manager

So my issue is that I have multiple filtered subdomains in the same GA account with the proper "include only traffic to the hostname that contains subdomain.domain.com" filters. I even had a local digital marketing company Anvil Media help me set it up.

BUT there are keywords showing up in my subdomain traffic reports that are obviously sending traffic to the main domain and not the subdomain. I know because a quick google search will confirm that the keyword in question is brining up the main domain and not the subdomain.

The filters do seem to be filtering most of the traffic out, but not all of it.

Any ideas? I've been reading help articles for days . . .

Answer (score 0):

Google search results are personalized. Person A may see the main domain and Person B could be seeing the sub-domain.

You should be able to confirm your filter is working correctly by doing a custom report using Page (dimension) and Pageviews (metric) and then filtering Page with "exclude Page containing SUB_DOMAIN_A." and seeing if you get any results. If you do get results your filter is wrong. If you don't then the filter is working, those keywords are bringing traffic to the sub-domain.

The landing page path dimension would be useful in determining which pages are causing the behavior you don't want.